# How to test after install deep linking on ios?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, deep-linking

I have a Flutter app and i need to detect the url that originated the app download in the stores. On android, i send firebase dynamic link X to some user, he opens it, the OS tries to open the app if installed or redirects to a landing page if not. Then in this page there is a link to Play store. If he downloads it, on first run the app detects correctly that it was launched from link X. So far, so good. For android, all i need to do is upload a test version of my app to play store and set my user as tester, so when the store link is opened, it shows the internal testing version instead of the production one. The problem is: on ios, i have not found a way to link directly to a test version on App store (everythng is handled inside test flight app), so i´m unable to test the whole process. Is there a way to replace the store link app with a test version for specific users?

Comment: You should be able to use TestFlight for testing the app as it should be working when downloaded from the App Store. 
For the specific users, you can send them the invite on TestFlight.

Comment: @ZeMoon i need my landing page to link to app store with a testflight version